# Error: A value of type 'LoginRepositoryImpl' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'LoginRepository' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

I use get_it package for dependency injection, and this error is new.

**The error:**

```
lib/injection.dart:164:11: Error: A value of type 'LoginRepositoryImpl' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'LoginRepository'.
 - 'LoginRepositoryImpl' is from 'lib/future/login/data/repository/login_repository_impl.dart'.
 - 'LoginRepository' is from 'lib/future/login/domain/repository/login_repository.dart'.
    () => LoginRepositoryImpl(
          ^
```

**login_repository_impl.dart:**

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepositoryImpl
    implements LoginRepository {
  final LoginRemoteDataSource loginRemoteDataSource;
  final LoginLocalDataSource loginLocalDataSource;

  LoginRepositoryImpl(
      {@required this.loginRemoteDataSource,
      @required this.loginLocalDataSource,
      @required NetworkInfo networkInfo})
      : super(
            baseLocalDataSource: loginLocalDataSource,
            networkInfo: networkInfo,
            baseRemoteDataSource: loginRemoteDataSource);

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, LoginResponse>> loginUser(String email, String password) {
    return checkNetwork(() async {
      try {
        final result = await loginRemoteDataSource.loginUser(email, password);
        if (result == null)
          return Left(ServerFailure(ErrorCode.SERVER_ERROR));
        else {
          await loginLocalDataSource.loginUser(
            result.data.authKey,
          );
          return Right(result.data);
        }
      } on ServerException catch (e) {
        if(e.errors != null) {
          final result = getErrorsList(e.errors);
          return result.fold((l) => Left(ServerFailure(ErrorCode.SERVER_ERROR)),
              (r) => Left(ServerFailure(e.errorCode, r)));
        }
        return Left(ServerFailure(e.errorCode));
      } catch (e) {
        return Left(ServerFailure(ErrorCode.SERVER_ERROR));
      }
    });
  }

}
```

**login_repository.dart:**

```
abstract class LoginRepository extends BaseRepository {
  Future<Either<Failure, LoginResponse>> loginUser(String email, String password);

}
```

**injection.dart:**

inside init function:

```
sl.registerLazySingleton<LoginRepository>(
    () => LoginRepositoryImpl(
      networkInfo: sl(),
      loginLocalDataSource: sl(),
      loginRemoteDataSource: sl(),
    ),
  );
```

**flutter doctor:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

I have tried the following:

*flutter clean*

*flutter pub upgrade*

*flutter pub downgrade*

updated get_it package to latest version

Comment: To me this doesn't look like a problem inside get_it but seems to be realted with the way your classes derive and implement each other.
Clould you try to directly create an Implementation object and asign it to a variable of the abstract type?

Comment: Yes you are right, I solved the problem by adding the implementation and the abstract class the same file, I don't know why when they are in separate files doesn't work.

Comment: That normally isn't a problem. But your combination of extends and implments might be a problem somehow. If you can make a small pure dart project that reproduces the same behaviour without get_it you should probably raise an issue on the Dart repositiory

Comment: I will try to use provider to know if the problem from my code or from dart sdk, thanks for your comments Thomas.

Comment: No, try it without any package, just check if the assignment works if you have them in separate files. It has nothing to do with get_it.

Comment: Ok i will try it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was fixed when I put the `LoginRepositoryImpl`  and `LoginRepository` 
in the same file.

I don't know what is the reason but it worked fine.